# How can in unity lift an entire object consisting of child elements into the air?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script that, when a ray hits an object, object rises into the air. But if the object consists of a parent element and children on which the Hinge Joint component hangs, then when the beam hits the parent element, the script does not work. When the beam hits the child elements, the script works (the entire object is lifted by a cell).How can I fix the creaking so that when the beam hits any part of an object element, the entire object rises?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LeviosoSpell : UtilitySpell
{
    public float levitationHeight = 1f; // Высота парения объекта
    public float levitationDuration = 3f;

    public override void Cast(Wand wand)
    {
        ToWorkingSpell(wand);
        StartCoroutine(TimeOfAction(wand));
        EventManadger.OnCombinationSpells(this);
    }


    public IEnumerator TimeOfAction(Wand wand)
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = new Ray(wand.FirePoint.position, wand.FirePoint.forward);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
           Transform chestParent = hit.transform.parent;


            if (chestParent != null)
            {
            Rigidbody[] allRigidbodies = chestParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Rigidbody>();

                foreach (Rigidbody rb in allRigidbodies)
                {
                    rb.useGravity = false; // Отключаем гравитацию для каждого дочернего элемента с Rigidbody
                }

                Vector3 levitationDirection = Vector3.up * Physics.gravity.magnitude;
                float levitationForce = levitationHeight;

                foreach (Rigidbody rb in allRigidbodies)
                {
                    rb.AddForce(levitationDirection * levitationForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);
                }

                yield return new WaitForSeconds(levitationDuration);

                foreach (Rigidbody rb in allRigidbodies)
                {
                    rb.useGravity = true; // Включаем гравитацию для каждого дочернего элемента с Rigidbody
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried using different verification conditions, but it still doesn't help. I tried disabling Hinge Joint, but this method is not suitable

Comment: The idea of joints in the first place is that you do not want to nest Rigidbody within each other ...